# No microphone input Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Lenovo T420

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, microphone

I was trying to do some recordings with my new jack splitter. It's a Y cable with a 3.5mm 4 segment male jack, connecting to the computer port, and two female 3.5mm sockets, one for headphones (green), and another one for microphone (pink).

When I connect my input device to the pink socket in my combo cable, and open `pavucontrol`, the Microphone input entry shows unplugged, even though I'm sure it's perfectly plugged in, and I'm sending audio thru the cable. I have unmuted the microphone thru `alsamixer -c 0` and come back to `pavucontrol` but still only Internal microphone shows connected. Microphone is still unplugged.

I don't understand what could be happening, could someone help? Thank you very much.

**OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64

Computer: Lenovo ThinkPad T420**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with my laptop (Asus S56CB), I **fixed it** by adding this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-dmic
```

at the end of this file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

then reboot.

If it doesn't work you should try to replace the **model** (laptop-dmic) with one of these: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt